# IIS Rewrite always returns 502 bad gateway while rewriting to external website

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

It is a small website deployed on IIS. I am using rewrite feature on this website to rewrite the http request to external website. Here is the rewrite settings in web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://about.gitlab.com/" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

It always returns `HTTP Error 502.2 - Bad Gateway`.

> HTTP Error 502.2 - Bad Gateway
> There was a connection error while trying to route the request.

If I just use an internal path pointing to a page inside this website, using a relative path, starting with `/`, then it is working fine. After changing to external website, it always returns `HTTP Error 502.2 - Bad Gateway`.

Anywhere need to update?

Comment: One of typical issues with ARR is that `preserveHostHeader` is by default `false`, https://github.com/lextm/iis_schema/blob/master/arr_schema.xml#L29

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-arr-using-frt-rules) to see details about 502.2 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I resolved the issue. It may not the solution for all `502 bad gateway` issue, but it resovled my problem.

In Application Request Rounting -> Cache Setting -> Memory Cache Duration. I set his value into 0. Then it is working as expected.

Comment: it should be the solution , thank you !!